# How to order_by a many to many field in template?

Tags: django

When I try to render a manytomany object in the template. My `models.py` is:

```py
class Class(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='member')
    texts = models.ManyToManyField(Messages)

class Messages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    messages = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I've rendered this in my template:

```html
    {% for text in class.texts.all %}
    <div class="card col-md-4 w-75 l-balloon mb-2">
        {{text.messages|linebreaks}}
        <span class="font-small d-block ml-auto mr-3">{{text.time}}</span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is what I used in my `views.py`:

```py
context = {
    "class": Class.objects.get(id=pk)
}
```

Here I am just passing a single object of the class where I want to render the texts of the related class. While rendering `{{text.messages|linebreaks}}` it is ordered by the values of `messages` attribute of `Message` class. I want this to be ordered by `time` attribute. How can I acheive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a Meta Class for your model and use 'Ordering'.
 `class Meta:
ordering = ['time']`